# IFCOUNT(A1:A300; AVERAGE(A1:A298)>298) Error?

Tags: excel

I want to Average A1:A298 values and if it is bigger than A298 values, i want to count A1:A300.

I tried this.

```
IFCOUNT(A1:A300; AVERAGE(A1:A298)>A298)
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `IFCOUNT` doesn't exist.

Try:

```
IF(AVERAGE(A1:A298)>A298;COUNT(A1:A300);"The average isn't larger than A298")
```